# Using trunc with ifelse gives different behavior than using trunc alone

Tags: r

I'm trying to change a column in a dataframe such that numbers < 10 are rounded to one decimal place. Numbers >= 10 should be truncated, everything after the decimal dropped.

Here is some code:

```
df <- tibble (
  x = c(1.2, 3.4, 6.7, 11.44, 15.9)
)

test_trunc_ifelse <- ifelse(df$x < 10, round(df$x, digits = 1), trunc(df$x))

test_trunc <- trunc(df$x)
```

and some results:

```
test_trunc_ifelse
[1]  1.2  3.4  6.7 11.0 15.0

test_trunc
[1]  1  3  6 11 15
```

I thought (and want) the `ifelse` to output this:

```
[1]  1.2  3.4  6.7 11 15
```

Why doesn't it do that? And how do I get that output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is two classes `numeric` and `integer` and it is not possible to have two classes in the same vector.

If you still want your expected output one hack is to convert it into character

```
test <- as.character(ifelse(df$x < 10, round(df$x, digits = 1), trunc(df$x)))
test
#[1] "1.2" "3.4" "6.7" "11"  "15"
```

But you cannot perform any mathematical calculations with this. You need to convert it to numeric or integer again for that.

```
as.numeric(test)
#[1]  1.2  3.4  6.7 11.0 15.0
as.integer(test)
#[1]  1  3  6 11 15
```